# axioms - How do i prove the following statement?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, axioms

So the statement i want to prove is the following:

$a > 0 \Leftrightarrow a+a^{-1} >1$ with $a\in R$

So far I've been able to prove that:

when $0<a<1$, then $a^{-1} >1$

and when $a>1$, then $a^{-1}<1$

But where do i go from here?

Can i just come to the conclusion that "Therefore $a+a^{-1}>1$ ?

Comment: When $a>1$ you need to show $a^{-1} > 0$, not $<1$. And you should at least mention the trivial case $a=1$. Then "$\Rightarrow$" is proven. 

"$\Leftarrow$" you could prove indirectly: if $a < 0$ then $a+a^{-1} < 0 < 1$.

Comment: The expression $\dfrac{a^2+1}a$ has the sign of its denominator. Note that $>1$ is somewhat arbitrary, $>0$ is good enough. (In fact $a+a^{-1}\ge2$.)

Answer (score 1):

If $a>0$ then $a^{-1}>0$

Now if $a$ is an integer, then $\frac1a$ is a real number between $0$ and $1$. So when we add them we get a real number which is greater than $a$. The smallest value $a$(if an integer)  is $1$ so $a+a^{-1}>1$.

Now if $a$ is a real number between $0$ and $1$ then $\frac1a>1$ which alone proves the statement.

Comment: Oh yes I will edit it